# Returning to ubuntu from xubuntu

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, recovery-mode

When I choose ubuntu option from the booting list as usual, it loads the xubuntu logo and then stucks in:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, X/Y files, Q/Z blocks.
```

*X, Y, Z and Q are some numbers.

I don't know what has happened because I have never installed xubuntu!
I have tried some troubleshootings through safe recovery mode, non has worked.
Could you please help me out back to normal ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Your question elicits more questions than answers. Are you sure you didn't install xfce or `xubuntu-desktop`? Packages and desktop environments don't spontaneously manifest themselves on your device, so there must have been *something*? If you have no clue how it got there, it will be difficult to determine how to get rid of it. Is the only trace of Xubuntu the splash screen, or does your system boot to an Xfce desktop?  Can you even boot to a desktop at all?  Your details are not very clear.

Comment: It might be related to X2go Client which was the only major installation I did before this issue. Maybe I should uninstall it in the recovery mode?!

Comment: how did you install `x2goclient`?  It's available in `universe` and does not have xfce as a dependency.  Did you install it via apt or the software center?  Or did you install it some other way?

Comment: I just uninstall it in the recovery mode as per the below instructions:
https://www.fosslinux.com/44293/how-to-install-and-uninstall-xfce-on-ubuntu.htm 

a step forward! now it shows the ubuntu splash screen but still, the above error exist plus the blow message:

/dev/...: clearing orphand inode ....

Comment: Orphaned inodes are often a symptom of hard drive failure and may necessitate an reinstall of the OS, depending on what parts of the file system were damaged.

Comment: The messages you post in your initial question are usually the result of user behavior (ie. *an unclean shutdown caused by users pulling power cable or holding power button down, rather than directing the system to cleanly shutdown via SysRq or other like commands*). The messages are not an error, but symptom of a problem such as *unclean* shutdown OR hardware failing as per prior comment (*the former is generally known and holding down power button to force a system off a common cause*).  I'd boot *live8 media and `fsck` partitions to check & correct issues after *unclean* shutdown.

Comment: Yes, I had to do an unclean shutdown, and this is the result. 
I just managed to get it back by uninstalling Nvidia driver and X2go through recovery mode root